# Issues with Blender/Unity 3D integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

We had a problem with models dissapearing in builds due to Blender version differences so everyone in the office had to update to Blender 2.8. But when I updated, something in the integration broke and now for a specific project, I can't see the models in the scene or in runtime.

The integration works perfectly fine for other projects running the same version of Blender (2.80) and Unity (2019.10f2). It also works fine on this specific project on other computers, the only difference being that they use Mac and I use Windows.

I replaced the Unity-BlenderToFBX.py file according to some tips I found on Google and while that stopped a lot of the errors which told me that I was using an older version of Blender when I wasn't but it still doesn't work.

The only error I get now is when I launch the project:
Failed to load component (MonoBehaviour)! Removing it!

But the thing is my coworkers also get the same error, and things work just fine.

Any ideas on how I can fix the problem?

Comment: You should consider to properly export the files from blender (export FBX) and not use the .blend files directly in Unity

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't fit our pipeline unfortunately. We have a very iterative and rapidly changing work flow which means we have to use .blend files.

Comment: well if you have to ... I'ld say also in a changing environment nothing speaks against simply re-export it after making changes ;)

Comment: Do the blend files have absolute or [relative paths](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/files/blend/save_load.html#relative-paths)? Absolute paths can break between mac/win. The [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) error (thats unity C# scripting) would indicate a unity installation issue, maybe scripts have hardcoded `.dylib` library names when win uses `.dll`